# Layered Navigation price filter attribute multiselect check box

Tags: magento-1.8, price, layered-navigation

I am working on Layered navigation of Magento. I want to implement the following:

1. Price filter with multiple check boxes.
2. Kit type with Radio buttons.
3. Ratings with multiple check boxes.

The same is shown in the below image also.

[image]

I have already tried to customize the [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo-6101.html) from magento-connect. But no luck. How can implement those multiselect filters.

Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One starting point can be this question on stackoverflow:
[Magento: textbox instead of multi select in layered navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480558/magento-textbox-instead-of-multi-select-in-layered-navigation/14489870)

Amasty's extension: [Improved navigation](http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html) solves your problem (quite popular extension).

Comment: Can i get it for free? Because it is very costly.

Comment: "Free" = you can build it (assuming that your time is free).

Comment: Yeah i have time but i need some guidance.

Comment: Read that first link I gave you... Be willing to allocate some effort, read and study... It's not realistic to expect other to give you code that you can copy-paste and have your module.4

Answer (score 1):

In one of upcoming projects I have something similar to implement. So spent some time to come up with a quick and dirty solution.

Please note that it's not a proper/complete solution. Core files have been changed along with 3rd party extension files.

Chances are it's not going to make sense in first iteration. But probaly it can reduce the development time.

- **Environment:** Magento 1.9
- **Extension Installed:** Amasty_Shopby

**Pre-requisite:** Some knowledge of how Layered navigation works in Magento is required.

**Summary of changes:**

**`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php`**

```
/**
 * Get all filter items
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getItems()
{
    if (empty($this->_items)) {
        $this->_initItems();
    }
    return $this->_items;
}
```

**`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php`**

A bunch of methods have been added to support multi-filter price behaviour. These methods have been copied from the core class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price` and it's parent classes. It will take some effort to study the code below and link it together:

```
    /**
     * Apply price range filter to product collection
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price $filter
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price
     */
    public function applyPriceRangeMulti($filter)
    {

        $reqParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($filter->getRequestVar());
        //validate filter
        $filterParams = array_unique(explode(',', $reqParams));

        $formattedParams = array();
        foreach($filterParams as $param){
            $filterParam = $this->_validatePriceFilter($param);
            if (!$filterParam) {
                return $this;
            }

            list($from, $to) = $filterParam;

            if ($from < 0.01 && $to < 0.01) {
                return $this;
            }

            $formattedParams[] = $filterParam;
        }

        $select = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
        $priceExpr = $this->_getPriceExpression($filter, $select, false);

        $andClauses = array();
        foreach($formattedParams as $filterParam){
            list($from, $to) = $filterParam;

            /*
             * Workaround for JS
             */
            if ($to == 0) {
               $to = '';
            }

            $filter->setInterval(array($from, $to));

            $index = array_search("{$from}-{$to}",$filterParams);

            $itemValue = $filterParams;

            if (false === $index){
                $itemValue[] = "{$from}-{$to}";
            }else {
                $itemValue[$index]  = null;
                unset($itemValue[$index]);
            }

            $itemValue = implode(',', $itemValue);

            $query = array(
                $filter->getRequestVar() => $itemValue,
                Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
            );
            $url = Mage::helper('amshopby/url')->getFullUrl($query);

            $text .= $this->_renderRangeLabel($from, $to) . " ";

            $children[] = array(
                'label' => $this->_renderRangeLabel($from, $to),
                'url' => $url,
            );

            if ($to !== '') {
                $to = (float)$to;
                if ($from == $to) {
                    $to += self::MIN_POSSIBLE_PRICE;
                }
            }

            if ($from !== '') {

                //$select->where($priceExpr . ' >= ' . $this->_getComparingValue($from, $filter));

                $fromExpr = new Zend_Db_Expr($priceExpr . ' >= ' . $this->_getComparingValue($from, $filter));
                $andString .= $fromExpr;
            }
            if ($to !== '') {

                //$select->where($priceExpr . ' < ' . $this->_getComparingValue($to, $filter));
                $toExpr = new Zend_Db_Expr($priceExpr . ' < ' . $this->_getComparingValue($to, $filter));

            }

            $andClauses[] =  "{$fromExpr} AND {$toExpr}";
        }

        foreach($andClauses as $andClause){
            $select->orWhere($andClause);
        }

        $state = $this->_createItem($filter, $text, $filterParams)
            ->setVar($filter->getRequestVar());

        if (count($children) > 1) {
            $state->setData('children', $children);
        }

        $filter->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($state);

        return $this;

    }

    /**
     * Prepare text of range label
     *
     * @param float|string $fromPrice
     * @param float|string $toPrice
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderRangeLabel($fromPrice, $toPrice)
    {
        $store      = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $formattedFromPrice  = $store->formatPrice($fromPrice);
        if ($toPrice === '') {
            return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('%s and above', $formattedFromPrice);
        } elseif ($fromPrice == $toPrice && Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_ONE_PRICE_INTERVAL)) {
            return $formattedFromPrice;
        } else {
            if ($fromPrice != $toPrice) {
                $toPrice -= .01;
            }
            return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('%s - %s', $formattedFromPrice, $store->formatPrice($toPrice));
        }
    }

    protected function _createItem($filter, $label, $value, $count=0)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('catalog/layer_filter_item')
            ->setFilter($filter)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setValue($value)
            ->setCount($count);
    }

    /**
     * Validate and parse filter request param
     *
     * @param string $filter
     * @return array|bool
     */
    protected function _validatePriceFilter($filter)
    {
        $filter = explode('-', $filter);
        if (count($filter) != 2) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($filter as $v) {
            if (($v !== '' && $v !== '0' && (float)$v <= 0) || is_infinite((float)$v)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $filter;
    }
```

**`app/code/local/Package/SomeExtension/Model/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price/Price17ce.php`**

This is an extension specific file that overrided the apply() method from parent class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`. In most cases this parent class will require modifications. To explain a bit `_applyPriceRange()` method has been changed to `_applyPriceRangeMulti()`. Definition of this method has been pasted above already. Again it's a copy-paste from the `_applyPriceRange()` for the most part.

```
protected function _applyPriceRangeMulti()
{
    $this->_getResource()->applyPriceRangeMulti($this);
}
```

Please put a comment if any one needs any more explanation.